# C : Get color with coordinates

Tags: c, colors, coordinates

Im newbie in C sorry,
I have problem about get color in C (not C++) and im using DEC-C++ 4.9.9.2

```
GetPixel(hdc,674,63)
```

I want to get color in x= 674 and y= 63 in any active tab windows, and show with messagebox.
How could i write in C code?

thanks for helping ^_^
GBU

Comment: `GetPixel()` is not a standard C function. What library is it from?

Comment: i dont know either....i just using common library and i found getpixel